# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. in foreach()

Tags: c#, foreach, invalidoperationexception, mdichild, mdiparent

I was using a button to output a form in the MDI parent. The frmUser does not have any code or anything, just a plain new form, and this is the only code I have in this form, and the foreach() is having an error of:

> InvalidOperationException was unhandled.

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

I do not know what is wrong and there are same error question as mine but different circumstances so it does not really help mine. So I wonder what is wrong with the foreach()

The code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MACRO
{
    public partial class frmAdmin : Form
    {
        public frmAdmin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool IsOpen = false;
            foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
            {
                if (f.Text == "frmUsers")
                {
                    IsOpen = true;
                    f.Focus();
                    break;
                }

                if (IsOpen == false)
                {
                    frmUsers users = new frmUsers();
                    users.MdiParent = this;
                    users.Show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which operation trigger this error? it should be part of stack trace.

Comment: Probably f.Focus?

Comment: The logic is broken anyway - the code that creates a new form and shows it (and thus changes the set of `OpenForms`) shouldn't be in the loop at all - it should be *after* the loop if it turned out that *none* of the forms were `frmUsers`. So fix the actual logic and the error caused by opening forms at the wrong time will go away also.

Comment: (Of course one might also observe that you can access forms by name from the `FormCollection` that `OpenForms` returns and so the loop isn't required at all)

Comment: I'm sure the other questions you found *would* help here. By showing a form within the loop, the collection `OpenForms` is modified (as a new one is added). However, as above, this logic is almost certainly incorrect.

Comment: @CharlesMager what should I do?

Comment: As @Damien_The_Unbeliever suggests, the form should be opened *after* the loop has completed and you know none of the open forms are the one you're looking for. At the moment you open it if the *first* one doesn't match.

Comment: ohh thanks sorry im just a beginner at this. Thanks for the help